# Bundle install fails on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, bundler, centos6

I've got a rails app I recently pushed to a 'production' VPS managed server.  I used Capistrano for deployment and it seems to have made it to the server just fine.  I changed to the application's current directory and ran bundle install to start getting everything set up and hit this error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151105-8574-y7clqw.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I'm unfamiliar with this error and this is uncharted territory for me, so I'm a little lost.  I was able to get postgres on the server [using this information from postgresql wiki.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation#Configure_your_YUM_repository)

I'm fairly sure this is a simple fix, I'm just not familar with setting up a new server, so I'm not sure what I'm doing here!

EDIT:

As was suggested below, I added the lib and dev packs to my server.  I have found pg_conf in `/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin`, but my application can't seem to find it, resulting in the error above.  when I attempt to execute `$ bundle install --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin` as suggested in the error output above, I recieve a `Unknown switches '--with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin'` error.

How should I map to the file?  Is there something else going on here I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh into your production machine and install the `postgresql-devel` package on that machine, this will solve the issue of `pg_config missing`:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```